# How can I remove the specific error message after regex validation is done?

Tags: javascript, html

The regex validation works but the error messages which have been displayed persist till the form is submitted. How can this be corrected so that after each attempt(Once the submit button is clicked) the input that has been validated will have the corresponding error message not displayed? *The attempt to implement this part is the last 2 else if statements, they also make the validation work partially. Take them out and the validation works but the error message issues persist.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    document.querySelector('#sbutton').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let phoneInput = document.querySelector('#phone').value;
        let phoneRegex = /^(0|\+234)[789]{0,1}([0-1]{1})([0-9]{8})$/;
        const phoneError = document.querySelector('#phoneErr');
        let inputV = document.querySelector('#budget').value;
        const errorMessage = document.querySelector('#errormsg');
        let form = document.querySelector("form");

        if (phoneInput == "" || !phoneRegex.test(phoneInput)) {
            phoneError.innerHTML = "Please enter a valid phone number";
            phoneError.style.display = "block";
        } else if (inputV == "" || inputV < 300000) {
            errorMessage.innerHTML = "Enter at least 300000"
            errorMessage.style.display = "block";
        } else if (phoneRegex.test(phoneInput)) {
            phoneError.innerHTML = "";
            phoneError.style.display = "none";
            return;
        } else if (inputV >= 300000) {
            errorMessage.innerHTML = ""
            errorMessage.style.display = "none";
            return;
        } else {
            phoneError.innerHTML = "";
            phoneError.style.display = "none";
            errorMessage.innerHTML = ""
            errorMessage.style.display = "none";
            form.submit();
        }
    })
})
```

```html
<form action="https://dragonmm.com" method="post">
                <div class="contact-box">
                    <div class="left1"></div>
                    <div class="right1">
                        <h2>Start</h2>
                        <label for="name"></label>
                        <input id="name" type="text" class="field" placeholder="Name" required>
    
                        <label for="email"></label>
                        <input id="email" type="text" class="field" placeholder="Email" required>
    
                        <label for="phone"></label>
                        <input id="phone" type="text" class="field" placeholder="Phone" required> 
                        <div id="phoneErr"></div>
    
                        <label for="budget"></label>
                        <input id="budget" type="text" name="budget" class="field budgetInput" placeholder="Budget" required>
                        <div id="errormsg"></div>
                        <button type="submit" value="Send" class="btn1" id="sbutton">Send</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: you can try adding event listeners to keydown of the inputs and checking for errors there instead of validating after button click

Comment: I could do that but I want to do it after the button is clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acutally, your regex method is not working properly in my system so I changed with my regex method. if phoneInput variable will generate any error then it will display this message "Please enter a valid phone number" and return from there. if number format will be correct than it will empty the phoneError. Take a look at this code.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        document.querySelector('#sbutton').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            let phoneInput = document.querySelector('#phone').value;
            let phoneRegex = /^(0|\+234)[789]?[0-9]{10}$/;
            const phoneError = document.querySelector('#phoneErr');
            let inputV = document.querySelector('#budget').value;
            const errorMessage = document.querySelector('#errormsg');
            let form = document.querySelector("form");
    
            if (phoneInput == "" || !phoneRegex.test(phoneInput)) {
                phoneError.innerHTML = "Please enter a valid phone number";
                return;
            } else {
                phoneError.innerHTML = "";
            }
            if (inputV == "" || inputV < 300000) {
                errorMessage.innerHTML = "Enter at least 300000";
                return;
            } else {
                errorMessage.innerHTML = "";
                form.submit();
            }
        })
    })
```